# JavaFX ColorPicker inside a ContextMenu

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to implement code to put a JavaFX ColorPicker inside of a ContextMenu so that when a Rectangle is right-clicked, the ContextMenu shows the ColorPicker and allows the user to set the color of the Rectangle to whatever the ColorPicker's value is. What I am currently doing is putting the ColorPicker inside of a MenuItem that goes inside the ContextMenu. However, I am encountering an issue where the ColorPicker breaks when the user selects the "Custom Color" link. I've already determined that this is an issue with JavaFX 8 that results from putting the ColorPicker inside of the MenuItem inside of the ContextMenu. Below is some code to show what I am trying to do and shows the issue.

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
primaryStage.setTitle("Test");

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(25,25,Color.LIGHTGREY);
ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem changeColor = new MenuItem();

changeColor.setGraphic(colorPicker);
contextMenu.getItems().add(changeColor);

rect.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent e){
        ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setStrokeWidth(4);
        if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
            contextMenu.show((Rectangle)e.getSource(),Side.TOP,0,0);
        }
    }
});

StackPane root = new StackPane();
root.getChildren().add(rect);
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
launch(args);
}
}
```

My question is if there might be another way I could add the ColorPicker to the ContextMenu or if there is another method entirely for me to receive the desired effect.

Comment: By 'ColorPicker breaks when the user selects the "Custom Color" link', I assume you mean that it causes Java to crash (which is the behavior I get with Java 8u20 on OS X when running your program).  I advise that you file a bug for this in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: I'll do that. Do yo have any ideas of a way that I can get this desired effect?

Comment: I have no other ideas at the moment, Leathis.  Others may have some ideas though and you may get some assistance or workaround advice from JavaFX developers when you post the bug.

Comment: Ok, I just posted it so I'll keep trying different things and wait to hear from them.  Thanks jewelsea.

Comment: Is there any solution? I'm also interested how this issue can be solved?